# Accessing memory from mmap extremely slow when multithreading

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, memory, concurrency

My task is to scan an entire disk to check for some properties of each block. I managed to do this using `mmap(2)`. However, it was pretty slow so I decided to multithread it. What I basically do is:

1. mmap() the disk
2. create x amount of threads
3. each thread starts reading from a block `(blocks per thread * thread index)` and goes up til `(start block + blocks per thread)`

I implemented a progress bar such that I can follow along the progression.

When I run it, it seems like it goes incredibly good; speeds are way faster than single thread. However, on disks of 10GB+, around having done about 20% - 30% the progress stalls. It then takes incredibly long such that a single thread would have been faster.

What is the reason for this fast progression in the start, but stalling later on?

Edit: Looks like I run out of memory. Since I'm pretty new, what would be the recommended way to iterate over all the blocks in a disk reliably?

Comment: I would assume whenever a thread reads a new block, it must be fetched from disk. If multiple threads read from different blocks you need to fetch from different areas of the disk alternatingly. If you are talking about good old spinning hard disks, that may take significant amount of time to jump between those areas. Just reading everything sequentially does not suffer from that penalty.

Comment: You might show how you `mmap` the disk. What options do you set? Did you add `PROT_WRITE`? Generally you should include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) into your question.

Comment: Even for SSDs, random reads can be slower than sequential reads.

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your check for these properties of a block, the check itself can be negligible compared to reading the block from disk. In that case it does not make much sense to spend any time thinking about multithreading etc. You can hardly speed up IO with more threads.

Comment: flushing to SSD drive?

Comment: @Gerhardh PROT_READ is the only one set, as I don't need to write. As for the map parameters, I experimented a bit but settled with MAP_PRIVATE, as I think MAP_SHARED is not needed?

Comment: @Gerhardh And I understand that maybe there's no benefit to multithreading here, but my examples show that in the start it indeed works way faster. I was mainly looking for an answer why that is and why it starts to slow down dramatically afterwards

Comment: Maybe you run out of RAM after a few GiB are loaded from disk. In worst case some swapping might happen before you can load more sectors. Or you just did something wrong which we can't see...

Comment: Please run the `free` command so to get information about the memory usage over time. Few run before the change in behaviour and few run after (separated from few seconds). We need such information to understand what is going on on your machine. Additionally, you can use `iotop` so to analyse your disc usage. Profiling is critical to understand such problems.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Indeed. I ran the command and `free -s 2` to print it every 2 seconds. It looks like I run out of memory. Since I need to iterate over the disk only once, do you know a better method than mapping the entire disk after which I iterate over it?

Comment: If you read data only once, there is nothing better. Otherwise, it depends of the locality of the memory accesses. Access to the same page are nearly guaranteed to be cached by the OS (it would be silly not to do that for any OS). For more pages, then the caching policy change from one OS to another so it is hard to tell.